# Reposition/realign div to line up scrollbar

Tags: css, html, css-float, scrollbar

I have a site built using 12 column 960 grid.

I'm using `float: right` to create two columns on the site, and have a scrollable area for my main area.  The problem is that the scrollbar wants to sit at the outer left edge of the div, which duffs up the look of it.

Amending the width of this area only narrows the div from the left hand edge of the area and the scrollbar remains firmly on the outer right edge.  Is this because this div is set to float right?

What can I do?

I tried to post an image to illustrate but I don't have enough reputation.. hope my description is illuminating enough!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please post some HTML and CSS in your question so that people can understand what you are trying to do. Try putting together a demo using http://www.jsfiddle.net; a demo will encourage people to show interest in your question.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks so much for the reply - I only just realised it was here.  I've found the solution and it was so simple it never occurred to me... margin-right on the div!  I don't know if that makes any sense with the limited information I've provided, but in any event; Thank again!

Comment: please close this question or answer it yourself for it to be considered answered